# Twitter Card Validator Internal Server Error Cards

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, twitter-card

I have validated my card URL. I got an internal server error. What is the issue? What can I do rectify this issue? Below is my URL:

https://www.bitgiving.com/aghanashini

Below are my meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@BitGiving">
<meta name="og:title" content="Documentary on a Unique River in India - Aghanashini | BitGiving">
<meta name="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="og:description" content="There are hardly any rivers left in India that are untouched. This is a story of one such rare river - Aghanashini, which is still untamed.">
<meta name="og:url" content="https://www.bitgiving.com/aghanashini">
<meta name="og:image" content="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bitgivingdata/event/5545__event1479405608.jpg">
```

I have enabled require all granted.
In robot.txt, Twitterbot is allowed, but to no success.